# RHEL 7.8 - Different behaviors between `service X start` and `systemctl start X`

Tags: redhat, systemd, service, rhel7

I'm currently setting up a RHEL 7.8 tomcat service and I'm having trouble with the `service` and `systemctl` commands.

Context:
the following file was set up on **/etc/init.d/tomcat**:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#
#
# chkconfig: 2345 20 80
# description:  Start up the Tomcat servlet engine.

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions


RETVAL=$?
CATALINA_HOME="<tomcat 9 folder location>"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_251"

case "$1" in
 start)
        if [ -f $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh  ];
          then
            echo $"Starting Tomcat"
            /bin/su saveweb -c "JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh"
        fi
        ;;
 stop)
        if [ -f $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh ];
          then
            echo $"Stopping Tomcat"
            /bin/su saveweb -c "JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh 15 -force"
        fi
        ;;
 *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

And this is the **/run/systemd/generator.late/tomcat.service** file:

```
# Automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator

[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat
Description=SYSV: Start up the Tomcat servlet engine.
Before=runlevel2.target
Before=runlevel3.target
Before=runlevel4.target
Before=runlevel5.target
Before=rhnsd.service
After=network-online.target
After=network.service

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat start
ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat stop
```

(I'll be honest here, I don't know how or who generated these files. I'm working with what was given to me)

This works fine for most use cases (starting service on system boot, using `systemctl start tomcat` and `systemctl stop tomcat` etc). We also set tomcat in a way that its **setenv.sh** defines a `CATALINA_PID` variable, so that starting/stopping the tomcat server directly through its scripts or through `systemctl` will work.

This is all because some users might, due to human error, start the tomcat service twice. We definitely don't want two tomcat instances.

So while testing it out, everything seemed to be working properly. When I use `systemctl start tomcat` twice, only the first instance of the tomcat service will be up - as expected.

However, it was pointed out that if someone uses `service tomcat start` while the previous service was online, the `service` program will first **stop** and then **start** the service.

So, in short:

```
# this works fine!
systemctl start tomcat
systemctl start tomcat # effectivelly ignored, maybe some log saying that there was a previous instance online. Good!
```

```
service start tomcat
service start tomcat # logs show that "stop" was called and then the service was started again. not good.
```

I'm super confused because everywhere I looked says that `service` is just a wrapper for `systemctl`. So what gives? Why does `service` have a different behavior than `systemctl` in this situation, and what should be done to fix it so that they are consistent?

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`service` is indeed a wrapper, but the way `service start` works in the presence of `/etc/init.d/tomcat` file is by stopping the existing instance, then starting another.

You can see how it works by `cat /sbin/service` - it's really a small script, and it states the reasoning to having to stop the service:

> LSB daemons that dies abnormally in systemd looks alive in systemd's eyes due to RemainAfterExit=yes
>   lets reap them before next start

The file `/run/systemd/generator.late/tomcat.service` is generated by SystemD itself from the legacy startup script `/etc/init.d/tomcat`. 
The `tomcat.service` is required for SystemD to be able to launch the service at boot time, or when you run it via `systemctl start`, etc.

If you *must* have the `service` behave exactly as `systemctl`, the best route would be having a "real" SystemD unit file for your Tomcat instance.

The `tomcat` package from repositories does come with [a SystemD unit](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/tomcat-7.0.76-10.el7_7.noarch.rpm.html) (note the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/tomcat.service` in the files section), so in all the likelihood you have installed Tomcat in an exotic/non-standard way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed explanation!